# Android Shape - Square with Circle and Different Top Color

Tags: android, xml-drawable, shapedrawable

I am trying to create a **shape drawable** like below.

[image]

where only the **top left** section is in different color **( here white )**. Thought placing a rectangle with smaller size would let me achieve this but I was wrong. Am I even going in the right direction?

Here's my **drawable.xml** file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <size android:width="15dp" android:height="15dp"/>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/black" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: create a custom `Shape` class and pass it to a `ShapeDrawable` constructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size android:width="60dp" android:height="60dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>



    <item android:left="40dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size android:width="30dp" android:height="30dp"/>
            <solid android:color="#ff0000" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:top="30dp" android:bottom="0dip">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size android:width="10dp" android:height="10dp"/>
            <solid android:color="#ff0000" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <stroke android:color="@android:color/black" android:width="1dp"/>
        <size android:width="60dp" android:height="60dp"/>
        <solid android:color="#ff0000" />
    </shape>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: Wow! that was fast and prefect. Thanks a ton.

Comment: if my size is vary means it's not working for me? what is logic here like 60dp,40dp,30dp,10dp ?

Comment: then you have to create this programatically

Comment: hi can you tell me how to reduce the size of the circle?
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size android:width="100dp" android:height="100dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <stroke android:color="@android:color/black" android:width="1dp"/>
            <size android:width="1dp" android:height="1dp"/>
            <solid android:color="#ff0000" />
        </shape>
    </item>